# XSL for each loop only grabbing data up to a certain Index

Tags: xslt, for-loop

How do I get xsl to grab items using a for each loop but only up to a certain index in what is selected. What I have tried doing is taking a number that is controlled by a webservice and returning items from out_data_info up to that index. The problem I have is that it only returns the data at that index and not everything up until that index.

```
<xsl:variable name="count" select=".//out_rec_count/text()"/>
<xsl:for-each select="//out_data_info[number($count)]">
<xsl:apply-templates select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Is there a way to do what I want while using a for each loop?

Comment: Looked at the `<` operator or a sibling axis?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the < operator because I guess it looks like an open carat.

Comment: I hope you never have to write text in XML with `<` in it then :(

Comment: The answer showed me that you can use `&lt;` as the `<` character. So you were on the right track, I just didn't know you could substitute the `<` character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//out_data_info[position() &lt;= $count]">
```

would select all `out_data_info` elements that are the first, second, ... `$count`-th `out_data_info` child of their parent element.  This may or may not be exactly right depending on the structure of your source XML (if you want an exact answer you'll have to edit the question to include an example of the input) - you may find you need

```
<xsl:for-each select="/descendant::out_data_info[position() &lt;= $count]">
```

instead, which would select the first `$count` occurrences of `out_data_info` in the whole document regardless of where they are within their parent element(s).

(This is one of the edge cases where `descendant::` and `//` mean slightly different things)